# What kind of array type is this?

Tags: arrays, database, multidimensional-array

I saw this snippet of data in my database, and I need to manipulate it, however I don't know what kind of array is this. It's surely not JSON though.

```
a:3:{s:7:"address";s:37:"Budapest I. kerület Kék golyó utca";s:3:"lat";s:10:"47.4996733";s:3:"lng";s:17:"19.02209300000004";}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.functions-online.com/unserialize.html

Think that is PHP serialized output. Try to do something like this

```
//php
$string = "a:3:{s:7:"address";s:37:"Budapest I. kerület Kék golyó utc.....";
$var = unserialize($string); 
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($var);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Worked great